# Element is not located in Javavscript with selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

```
await driver.findElement(By.id('closeBtn')).click();
```

or

```
await driver.findelement(By.xpath(//*[@id="closeBtn"].click();
```

Here, when i apply above condition for pop-up but it cannot performed using this.

Error is showing like this:

> **Unable to locate element: //*[@id="closeBtn"]**

Comment: please elaborate question?

Comment: I have create a script in javascript using selenium webdriver. And here i have added one line code where it cancel the Pop-up message. when i click on F12 and check it's locator then it shows <div id="closeBtn"> so i simply put line by ID and XPATH but both conditions i have faced error

Comment: Can you share the HTML code? 
Pop-up is window pop-up or just pop-up/alert kinda on the page?

Comment: <div id="closeBtn" style="cursor: pointer; width: 16px; height: 16px; top: 0px; right: 0px; position: absolute; user-select: none; pointer-events: auto; display: block; opacity: 1;">

Answer (score 0):

Anyone?

JS Code:await driver.findElement(By.id('closeBtn')).click();

F12 Code: